# Optimize sql query with multiple joins on single table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

tbl_picklist table

```
id     value
1      John
2      Mumbai
3      San Diego
4      CA
5      Jerry
```

tbl_user table

```
id     picklist_id_name    email
1      1                   john@test.com
2      8                   jerry@gmail.com
```

tbl_profile table

```
id     user_id   picklist_id_addr    picklist_id_addr2   designation
1       1         3                   5                   Dev
3       2         7                   3                   QA
```

Picklist is table where you will get values of address, address2 and name,
I wrote query which give me desired result

```
SELECT
    u.email,
    p1.value AS username,
    p2.value AS addr1,
    p3.value AS addr2
FROM tbl_user u
LEFT JOIN tbl_picklist AS p1
    ON u.picklist_id_name = p1.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_profile pr
    ON pr.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_picklist AS p2
    ON p2.id = pr.picklist_id_addr
LEFT JOIN tbl_picklist AS p3
    ON p3.id = pr.picklist_id_addr2
```

Result:

```
email            username      addr1        addr2
john@test.com    John          Mumbai       San Diego
jerry@gmail.com  Jerry         CA           Mumbai
```

To get above result, i needed to write 3 joins on picklist table, 
is there any other way in which i can get result only with the one join on picklist table?
I have this kind of table structure in application, many values are stored in picklist table, its taking to much time to execute this kind of queries.

Comment: The problem aren't the joins, it is that you haven't tuned your query.  Have you applied any index yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes there are indexes on all tables

Comment: Which columns have an index?

Comment: in picklist table, value column

Comment: please update your post with the output from `explain analyze` and provide the exact index definitions that are applied to those tables.

Comment: @sarvesh Index on the id column.

Answer (score 2):

The current Database structure isn't correct.
If you have rights, you should rebuild it to optimize your queries and to follow normalization forms.
For example, picklist_id_addr, picklist_id_addr2 and their values should be in one table, which you would join on picklist_id_name or user_id.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest adding a series of indices to your tables with the hopes of speeding up the query, until I realized that the bigger problem is your current table design.  The biggest offender is the following table `tbl_picklist`:

```
id     value
1      John
2      Mumbai
3      San Diego
4      CA
5      Jerry
```

You are storing all sorts of information about a user in a single unnormalized column.  Instead, I would recommend just having two tables, one for user information and the other for address information.  Link users to addresses via a primary-foreign key relationship.  For example:

```
tbl_user
id | email           | designation | address_id
1  | john@test.com   | dev         | 1
2  | jerry@gmail.com | QA          | 2
```

and

```
tbl_address
id | city      | state     | country
1  | San Diego | CA        | USA
2  | Mumbai    | Bollywood | India
```

Under this simplified schema, you would only need a single query to build out entire user records:

```
SELECT
    t1.email,
    t1.designation,
    t2.city,
    t2.state,
    t2.country
FROM tbl_user t1
INNER JOIN tbl_address t2
    ON t1.address_id = t2.id
```

As an example, if you still needed to optimize the above query, or something similar to it, you would need only worry about a single join, and no `WHERE` clause.  In this contrived example, an index on `tbl_user.address_id` should do the trick.